# How can I hide attributes from layer?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to hide 3 required fields from a layer:

```
#Making invisible the fields we're not interested in
desc = arcpy.Describe('fl_target_output_1')
field_info = desc.fieldInfo
# List of fields to hide
fieldsToHide = ['OBJECTID','Shape','Shape_Length']
for i in range(0, field_info.count):
    if field_info.getFieldName(i) in fieldsToHide:
        field_info.setVisible(i, 'HIDDEN')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('fl_target_output_1', 'fl_target_output_2', "", "", field_info)
fc_target_output_2 = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb\target_output_2'
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management ('fl_target_output_2', fc_target_output_2)
```

The above code does not throw any error but it doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this code appears not to be working is because it makes no sense!

If the fields in `fieldsToHide` where anything else then this code would execute as expected.

But you have deliberate hidden system fields which are the **bare minimum** of a FeatureClass. You then copy the new layer using **CopyFeatures** which implies you want to create a FeatureClass. How can you create a FeatureClass if SHAPE is not a field? You cannot.

If you are wanting to hide these fields but still treat the dataset as a spatial dataset then you want to create a LayerFile with the fields turned off and this would point to the source FeatureClass.

Comment: I see what you mean. But be aware that I am not trying to delete them, just trying to hide them. The reason I want to hide them is because I want to export that layer table to an excel file, and I do not want to show those 3 system fields. So, following your advice I am exporting to an excel file the layer with those fields turned off (not the feature class):

<arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('fl_target_output_1', 'fl_target_output_2', "", "", field_info)>
<arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion('fl_target_output_2', out_xls)>

It still doesn't work. The excel file shows all fields.

Comment: Actually, funnily enough, the excel file does not show those 3 system fields, but just 2 of them ('shape' is not shown).

Comment: Well if the final end product is an Excel worksheet (you really should have mentioned that) then I would be looking into making a Table View of your dataset and drop the fields pertaining to spatial data.